# Имитация длительного нажатия клавиши

Tags: javascript

Меня интересует
Как медленно физически нажать на кнопку с помощью javascript на веб странице сайта?

Обычно в авторежиме происходит быстрое нажатие на кнопку, без визуального эффекта, то есть клик, который не виден визуально

В Общем как сделать так чтобы кнопка среагировала в авторежиме, как будто на нее реально нажали, потом отпустили нажатую кнопку, вот собственно вот так показать физический клик по кнопке.

вот нашел фрагмент команды например

```js
  addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 32 && event.ctrlKey)
      console.log("Продолжаем!");
  });
```

> События «keydown» и «keyup» дают информацию о физическом нажатии
>   кнопок. А если вам нужно узнать, какой текст вводит пользователь?
>   Создавать его из нажатий кнопок – неудобно. Для этого существует
>   событие «keypress», происходящее сразу после «keydown» (и
>   повторяющееся вместе с «keydown», если клавишу продолжают удерживать),
>   но только для тех кнопок, которые выдают символы. Свойство объекта
>   события charCode содержит код, который можно интерпретировать как код
>   Unicode.

Я так понимаю это часть действия, перед тем как нажимают на кнопку ее находят, она реагирует и после уже команды клик происходит нажатие на кнопку.

То есть я о чем? чтобы имитировать реальное нажатие на кнопку, кнопку(ссылку), а не программный переход по сайту. Как реально это лучше сделать?

Answer (score 2):

используйте css3 transition-delay.

код примерно будет такой:

```css
button:hover {
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}
button:active {
  background-color: green;
  transition: all 5s ease;
}
button:focus {
  background-color: blue;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}
```

```html
<button>Click me!</button>`
```

Comment: Если можно то подробно привести пример, я еще в этом вопросе не  очень подкован, то есть пример с кнопкой и медленное нажатие на нее, программный код на css или java скрипт продемонстрируйте пожалуйста.

Comment: Ок. попробую ваш совет  css3 transition-delay.

Comment: а в java скрипте это разве нельзя реализовать? в java мне кажется все лаконичней и просто. ладно попробую в css еще

Comment: добавил пример в комментарии

Comment: OK. Что то происходит, но не так как хотелось бы. кнопочка становится красной, когда я уже сам кликаю на нее. нужно в авторежиме

Answer (score 2):

Вот реализация, остальное по примеру можете накрутить сами )

```js
(function(){
addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 32 && event.ctrlKey)
      document.getElementById('btn').classList.add('active');
  });
})()
```

```css
button.active { background-color: green;transition: all 5s ease; }
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click me!</button>
```

Это с покраской, но мне нравиться больше вот эта реализация

```js
(function(){
addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 32 && event.ctrlKey)
      document.getElementById('btn').classList.add('active');
   setTimeout(function(){
   document.getElementById('btn').classList.remove('active');
   },1000)
  });
})()
```

```css
button.active { border-style: inset;  background: red; color:#fff;}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую , попозже отпишусь.